# "Failed to construct kafka consumer" using Apache Drill

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-drill

I am using the Apache Drill (1.14) JDBC driver in my application which consumes the data from the Kafka. The application works just fine for some time and after few iterations it fails to execute due to the following `Too many files open` issue. I made sure there are no file handle leaks in my code but still nor sure why this issue is happening?

It looks like the issue is happening from with-in the Apache drill libraries when constructing the Kafka consumer. Can any one please guide me help this problem fixed?

The problem perishes when I restart my Apache drillbit but very soon it happens again. I did check the file descriptor count on my unix machine using `ulimit -a | wc -l` & `lsof -a -p <PID> | wc -l` before and after the drill process restart and it seems the drill process is considerably taking a lot of file descriptors. I tried increasing the file descriptor count on the system but still no luck.

I have followed the Apache Drill storage plugin documentation in configuring the Kafka plugin into Apache Drill at https://drill.apache.org/docs/kafka-storage-plugin/

Any help on this issue is highly appreciated. Thanks.

JDBC URL: `jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost:31010;schema=kafka`

NOTE: I am pushing down the filters in my query
`SELECT * FROM myKafkaTopic WHERE kafkaMsgTimestamp > 1560210931626`

````
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException: DATA_READ ERROR: Failed to fetch start/end offsets of the topic  myKafkaTopic

Failed to construct kafka consumer

[Error Id: 73f896a7-09d4-425b-8cd5-f269c3a6e69a ]
    at org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException$Builder.build(UserException.java:633) ~[drill-common-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.kafka.KafkaGroupScan.init(KafkaGroupScan.java:198) [drill-storage-kafka-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.kafka.KafkaGroupScan.<init>(KafkaGroupScan.java:98) [drill-storage-kafka-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.kafka.KafkaStoragePlugin.getPhysicalScan(KafkaStoragePlugin.java:83) [drill-storage-kafka-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.AbstractStoragePlugin.getPhysicalScan(AbstractStoragePlugin.java:111) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.logical.DrillTable.getGroupScan(DrillTable.java:99) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.logical.DrillScanRel.<init>(DrillScanRel.java:89) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.logical.DrillScanRel.<init>(DrillScanRel.java:69) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.logical.DrillScanRel.<init>(DrillScanRel.java:62) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.logical.DrillScanRule.onMatch(DrillScanRule.java:38) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoRuleCall.onMatch(VolcanoRuleCall.java:212) [calcite-core-1.16.0-drill-r6.jar:1.16.0-drill-r6]
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.volcano.VolcanoPlanner.findBestExp(VolcanoPlanner.java:652) [calcite-core-1.16.0-drill-r6.jar:1.16.0-drill-r6]
    at org.apache.calcite.tools.Programs$RuleSetProgram.run(Programs.java:368) [calcite-core-1.16.0-drill-r6.jar:1.16.0-drill-r6]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.transform(DefaultSqlHandler.java:429) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.transform(DefaultSqlHandler.java:369) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.convertToRawDrel(DefaultSqlHandler.java:255) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.convertToDrel(DefaultSqlHandler.java:318) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.DefaultSqlHandler.getPlan(DefaultSqlHandler.java:180) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getQueryPlan(DrillSqlWorker.java:145) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getPlan(DrillSqlWorker.java:83) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.runSQL(Foreman.java:567) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.run(Foreman.java:266) [drill-java-exec-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:765) ~[kafka-clients-0.11.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:633) ~[kafka-clients-0.11.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.kafka.KafkaGroupScan.init(KafkaGroupScan.java:168) [drill-storage-kafka-1.14.0.jar:1.14.0]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:129) ~[kafka-clients-0.11.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:156) ~[kafka-clients-0.11.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:160) ~[kafka-clients-0.11.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:701) ~[kafka-clients-0.11.0.1.jar:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollCreate(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.<init>(EPollArrayWrapper.java:130) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:69) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:127) ~[kafka-clients-0.11.0.1.jar:na]```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is because the kafka storage plugin never explicitly closes its connections to kafka.
It relies on the idle timeout at the server ( connections.max.idle.ms ) which defaults to 10 minutes.
I saw exactly the same issue when running queries for a few minutes - and we reduced the default timeout to verify that was the case.